# How to edit lock classes in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want add new library to my project, and show me error. I want rename file to not show me error, but I can't edit file and show me this error!

Please see my error image:

[image]

How can I fix it and edit this file?

Comment: You're trying to edit files in the wrong folder. Look under your `/src/res/values` folder for the `colors.xml` file. That's the one you should be editing.

Comment: @MikeM. , tnx but i need edit this. how can i it?

Comment: Edit the correct file. The file shown in the image will be updated to match it when you next rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing a file which was imported from another project. I don't see the path to the file, but I assume that it is in the `build` folder. However, the project containing this file is `MaterialDesign`, you can see it in the comment. Edit that file instead of editing the imported one. The changes will be reflected when you rebuild the project.